# Android Action Bar Sherlock Tabs Icon for each tab from resources

Tags: android, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I am using example from Action Bar Sherlock Fragment Tabs Pager. What I am trying to do is set different icon image for each tab. Text for each tab is not necessary, it can be included in image file. Is there a simple solution to this problem.

Answer (score 5):

This is what I do and works. Create the tabs menu and add the text (no needed in your case), the fragment to open and the Icon:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
     .setText("Tab title")
     .setTabListener(new ResultadosSorteosFragment())
     .setIcon(R.drawable.resultados_sorteos);
```

My problem is that I want to put the image under the text. 
I hope it´s what you need

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the sample in the ABS *FragmentTabsPager*, this is what you can do:

**This is to just show icon + label text :**

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("category").setIndicator("my label text", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.collections_labels) ),
            CategoryFragmentActivity.CategoryFragment.class, null); //
```

**This is to just show icon only:**

```
mTabsAdapter.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("category").setIndicator("", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.collections_labels) ),
            CategoryFragmentActivity.CategoryFragment.class, null); //
```